# In Python can you add elements from a list to the values of a dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to add the elements of a list of lists to the values of a dictionary.

I have created a list with elements from a file that looks like this:

```
list_of_lists = [[966], [1513, 2410], [2964, 1520, 604]....]
```

I am trying to add this list to a dictionary that I have made to look like this:

```
{'Youngstown': ['OH', 4110, 8065, 115436], 'Yankton': ['SD', 4288, 9739, 
12011], 'Yakima': ['WA', 4660, 12051, 49826]....]
```

I have tried the following code:

```
 x = 1
 for x in d2.values():
     d2.append(list_of_list)
 print(d2)
```

I am not even sure that this is something that is possible, but I am trying to get the dictionary to be:

```
{'Youngstown': ['OH', 4110, 8065, 115436], 'Yankton': ['SD', 4288, 9739, 
12011, [966]], 'Yakima': ['WA', 4660, 12051, 49826, [1513, 2410]]....]
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What happens with the Youngstown list? More generally, could you clarify how the inputs and outputs should map?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark the Youngstown list should not be appended. The index that I am aiming to start at is 'Yankton' with the first element from list_of_lists being appended to the end of the Yankton list.

Comment: So append the lists starting with the second key?

Comment: @BrokenBenchmark Correct. That is why I thought if I started x at the index of 1 I would be able to do this but it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know there are more ways to do that, But I think this is more readable and understandable code.

```py
list_of_lists = [[966], [1513, 2410], [2964, 1520, 604]] 

dict_ = {'Youngstown': ['OH', 4110, 8065, 115436], 'Yankton': ['SD', 4288, 9739, 
12011], 'Yakima': ['WA', 4660, 12051, 49826]}

i = 0
# list(dict_.items())[1:] is the list of all keys and values except first one.
for key,value in list(dict_.items())[1:]:
    dict_[key] = value+[list_of_lists[i]]
    i+=1
print(dict_)
```

Comment: this does help and makes more sense than what I was doing. I am still new to python so just playing around and trying to learn. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You do `x = 1`, and then immediately you do `for x in d2.values()`. This overwrites `x` with each element of `d2.values()`. If you want to start from the second item in `d2.values()`, you need to do create an iterator and skip the first value:

```
d2_iter = iter(d2.values())
next(d2_iter) # Consume one element
for item in d2_iter: # Iterate over the remaining iterator
    # Do what you want here.
```

Another problem is that you append the *entire list-of-lists* to *every value* in `d2`. Don't do that. Instead use `zip()` to iterate over the list-of-lists and the values in `d2` simultaneously

```
d2_iter = iter(d2.values())
next(d2_iter) # Consume one element
for item_from_dict, item_to_append in zip(d2_iter, list_of_lists): 
    item_from_dict.append(item_to_append)
```

which leaves you with:

```
{'Youngstown': ['OH', 4110, 8065, 115436],
 'Yankton': ['SD', 4288, 9739, 12011, [966]],
 'Yakima': ['WA', 4660, 12051, 49826, [1513, 2410]]}
```

Note that appending like this only works because lists are mutable. If you had an immutable type like tuples as the values of `d2`, you'd have to create a new tuple and assign it to the key:

```
d3 = {'Youngstown': ('OH', 4110, 8065, 115436), 'Yankton': ('SD', 4288, 9739, 12011), 'Yakima': ('WA', 4660, 12051, 49826)}

d3_iter = iter(d2.keys())
next(d3_iter) # Consume one element

for key_from_dict, item_to_append in zip(d3_iter, list_of_lists): 
    new_item = d3[key_from_dict] + (item_to_append,) # Create a new item
    d3[key_from_dict] = new_item
```

and you'd get

```
{'Youngstown': ('OH', 4110, 8065, 115436),
 'Yankton': ('SD', 4288, 9739, 12011, [966]),
 'Yakima': ('WA', 4660, 12051, 49826, [1513, 2410])}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.islice()` to skip the first element, and then use `zip()` to pair each list value with the list to append:

```py
from itertools import islice
for lst_value, lst_to_append in zip(islice(d2.values(), 1, None), list_of_lists):
    lst_value.append(lst_to_append)
    
print(d2)
```

This outputs:

```py
{
 'Youngstown': ['OH', 4110, 8065, 115436],
 'Yankton': ['SD', 4288, 9739, 12011, [966]],
 'Yakima': ['WA', 4660, 12051, 49826, [1513, 2410]]
}
```